# C# combox box owner draw

Tags: c#

My combobox is empty.

```
   public frmDlgGraphOptions()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.comboBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        arr = new String[4];
        arr[0] = "Solid Line";
        arr[1] = "Dashed line";
        arr[2] = "Dotted Line";
        arr[3] = "Dotted Line";
         imageArr = new Image[4];
         imageArr[0] = new Bitmap("C:\\SolidLine.png");
        imageArr[1] = new Bitmap("C:\\dashedline.png");
        imageArr[2] = new Bitmap("C:\\Dotted.png");
        imageArr[3] = new Bitmap("C:\\Dotted.png");

        comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBox1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(comboBox1_DrawItem);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 1;    
        this.comboBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((System.Byte)(192)), ((System.Byte)(192)), ((System.Byte)(255)));
        this.comboBox1.ItemHeight = 20;
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(84, 137);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 26);
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
```

Here's the code for OnDrawItem

```
 private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Let's highlight the currently selected item like any well 
        // behaved combo box should
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Bisque, e.Bounds); 
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageArr[e.Index], new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));   
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Bisque, e.Bounds);
        //is the mouse hovering over a combobox item??            
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == 0)
        {
            //this code keeps the last item drawn from having a Bisque background. 
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.Bounds);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(imageArr[e.Index], new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y));
        }
```

First of all, I dont see any items in the combo box. I see the empty combo box.
Also, when I hover on the combo box, e.index= -1 and throws an error

Thank u
Sun

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `Paint` Event and set the `ownerdraw` property to `True`

Comment: could u pls explain y I should override the Paint event.

Comment: Since your are painting it yourself